# QT QSqlDatabase, Add to Visual Studio Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, visual-c++

I am looking for direction on how I might include the QT ODBC source in my Visual Studio 2010 executable. My project requires a modification of the SQLResult class and prefer to include the source in my application instead of linking in the object configure -static.

FWIW: I am a registered Enterprise user with a valid license.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did... I do hope that these steps are useful to others.

My Environment: Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Download build from QT
Extract Build to directory...
C:\Qt\qt-everywhere-enterprise-src-5.2.1\

For each (x86/x64) platforms:
Program \Visual Studio Tools \ command prompt
create directory for QT platform

In my case: c:\qt\x86 and c:\qt\x64
Set the environment path to QT base:

QTDIR=C:\Qt\x86\qt-everywhere-enterprise-src-5.2.1\qtbase

At the command prompt:

set PATH=%CD%\qtbase\bin;%PATH%

Include any modules: Note -static

configure -static -prefix %CD%\qtbase -qt-sql-odbc -opengl desktop

nmake

---

For sql plug in:

---

cd src/sql

Create a VSProj file and include in your project.

qmake -tp vc

In Visual Studio ensure the VS Addin is installed on the system.  At the VS Menu Qt5 menu. Selection options. Create a build
to associate the VS addin to.

c/C++ hive
 General Additional Include:

```
.\GeneratedFiles;.;$(QTDIR)\include;
.\GeneratedFiles\$(ConfigurationName);
$(QTDIR)\include\QtCore;
$(QTDIR)\include\QtGui;
$(QTDIR)\include\QtSql;
$(QTDIR)\include\QtWidgets;
$(QTDIR)\include\QtNetwork;
$(QTDIR)\include\QtConcurrent;
.\header;
$(QTDIR)\plugins\platforms;
%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

Ensure all libraries are referenced in VS Project properties\linker\input\additional dependencies
Linker \ General \ Additional Library Directories

$(QTDIR)\lib;$(QTDIR)\plugins\platforms;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)